# Using legend onClick default function in custom onClick function in ChartJs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I wanted to do update percentage values in the pie chart when a label is clicked so I though that I can add the default legend onClick function into a custom function that also updates percentages values.

ChartJs version = 3.9.1

These are my chart options:

```
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins:{
        legend: {
          onClick : function (e, legendItem, legend){
            chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onClick(this, e, legendItem)
          },
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
            text: name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1),
            },
        datalabels: {
          formatter: (value, ctx) => {
              let sum = 0;
              let dataArr = ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].data;
              dataArr.map(data => {
                sum += data;
            });
            let percentage = (value*100 / sum).toFixed(2)+"%";
            return percentage;
        },
        color: '#fff',
      },
    },
      
  },
```

And I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isDatasetVisible')

**Edit**

Using this legends options (I copied and pasted onClick default func from source code)

```
legend: {
  onClick : function (e, legendItem, legend){
    const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
    const ci = legend.chart;
    if (ci.isDatasetVisible(index)) {
      ci.hide(index);
      legendItem.hidden = true;
    } else {
      ci.show(index);
      legendItem.hidden = false;
    };
  },
```

I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_resolveAnimations')

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to solve it. It seems "chart.defaults.plugins.legend.onClick" its outdated. What "onClick" func really does is this:

```
    legend.chart.toggleDataVisibility(legendItem.index);
    legend.chart.update();
```

So I copy this lines and pasted inside options.plugins.legend.onClick